# Vertex Vertices Weight Paint

Tags: vertices, weight-painting, vertex-paint

I am having a weight paint issue, I can't figure out way this wraps up the way it does, it twists at the ankle and dissforms. Can you help?

[image: Weight Paint Issue]

blend file:
[image]

Comment: It looks like control bone and deform bone have different bone roll. This causes rotation of deform bone in pose mode, thus weird mesh deformation. It's just a wild guess though.It's impossible to say for sure without seeing the file. You also have scripts auto-run disabled, which can cause problems if this rig is script driven.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Was helpful to see the file. Bone roll 180 degrees and all is fine.

[image]

Comment: This did not solve it.

Comment: Drop your file here http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/ and someone might find the problem...

Comment: Done!  added the file, I am still clueless.

Comment: Updated answer ...